# Нахождение наибольшей общей подпоследовательности двух списков

Tags: python, list

```
 def lcs(a, b):
    p=range(max(len(a),len(b)))
    c=[(j-i,a[i:j+1])for i in p for j in p if a[i:j+1]in b]
    print([y for x,y in c if x==max(c)[0]and y])
    '''
    Работает с:
    a = "1231359820"
    b = "0123134825"
    Не работает с:
    a = [1,2,3,13,5,9,8,2,0]
    b = [0,1,2,3,13,4,8,2,5]
    '''
```

У меня есть код для нахождения наибольшей общей последовательности в двух строках. Как сделать так, чтобы функция работала непосредственно со списками, а не со строками?
Без преобразования списков в строки.

Comment: Это RU версия стека. Не нужно транслейта. пишите по русски.

Comment: [Find indexes of sequence in list in python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459493/find-indexes-of-sequence-in-list-in-python) вместо `a[i:j+1] in b`

Comment: Не сможете подробнее объяснить, что именно вместо a[i:j+1] in b и как это должно работать?

Comment: В языке нет готовой функции, проверяющей присутствие последовательности в списке, аналогичной проверке присутствия подстроки в строке. Вам надо ее реализовать самому. Как? Пример по ссылке. И раз вам нужен только факт вхождения, вместо `indexes.append` достаточно `return True`.

Comment: Понял, большое спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таких непростых алгоритмах, нет смысла экономить строчки кода. Нужно писать явно, иначе потом трудно разобраться.

```
def sequential_slice(iterable, length):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    assert 0 < length <= len(pool)
    tails = (pool[s:] for s in range(length)) # Срезы не ленивы?
    return zip(*tails)

def sequence_in_list(sequence, lst):
    pool = tuple(sequence)
    return any((pool == s for s in sequential_slice(lst, len(pool))))

def lcs(a, b):
    if len(a) > len(b):
        a, b = b, a
    for l in reversed(range(1, len(a)+1)):
        seq = [subseq for subseq in sequential_slice(a, l) if sequence_in_list(subseq, b)]
        if seq:
            break
    return seq


a = "1231359820"
b = "0123134825"
print(lcs(a, b)) #-> [('1', '2', '3', '1', '3')]
a = [1,2,3,13,5,9,8,2,0]
b = [0,1,2,3,13,4,8,2,5]
print(lcs(a, b)) #-> [(1, 2, 3, 13)]
```

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо за разъяснения. Нельзя ли как-то реализовать этот алгоритм через списковые включения? Как было в примере со строками, только для списков? Я в любом случае отмечу ваш ответ как правильный, но был бы очень благодарен, если поможете, или объясните, почему так нельзя.

Comment: @MaxI На списки переделывать не буду, не вижу смысла. А в декларативном (функциональном) стиле, смысл переписать есть. Сам периодически сталкиваюсь и вечно горожу всякую чушь а-ля `[i+j:i+1]`, а через месяц, мучительно разбираюсь, зачем я это сделал. Согласитесь, решение получилось весьма элегантное. Причем работает как со списками, так и со строками.

Comment: Согласен. Спасибо.